# T4 template and EF with Code Generator from database schema Application

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, t4

I am currently in process of putting a process (using a windows application) in place where EF's POCO objects classes can be generated by pointing this app to the database table(s).

I have seen T4 templates and the VS Addin which helps to achieve this in VS. However it requires T4 template file on the VS solution. We do not want to go through this route. What we want is to just copy the classes generated by this app to the solution so it can be used.

The way T4 template works is that as soon as you make a change in the template it applies to the Class file. What I would like to do is to point the new App to the database and say tables A,B,C. The app will read the columns,types,relationships and create corresponding classes to a folder. Developer then Copy these classes and paste into VS solution. Longer terms plan then to extend this app to write repository classes.

I have rough idea but not a clear picture. Does anyone has any pointers about how about can I go to achieve this?

Thanks

Edit: This is purely in mind using EF Code first.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems you are asking is "Can my T4 templates live in a separate solution to my output code?".

Yes. You can do that.

Comment: Yes and No. Yes I want it to be separate but it need to generate the code from my app and not when I make change and save the template..

Comment: also the goal behind this exercise is to make life easy for developer. For a developers' day to day activities they dont need to get involved into T4 template mech. They can just use this app to get the code with minimum effort.